# Long/big infopath form issue

Tags: forms, sharepoint, infopath

I have created infopath form with Infopath 2010. This is really long and big. Users would like to fill up the form and save the form and complete the form later since the form is big. Would their be any option to satisfiy this request? Can we any add save button? Any thoughts?

Have anyone else had this issue before?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I haven't written any code. Just designed the form using infopath.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your form I am not sure if this answer will help, but here is a scenario that would achieve the result you want without the need for code:

1. On your form, include a means for the user to indicate the completion status of the form. You could do this in several ways - for example, a "Form is complete" checkbox, a "Form status" field with a dropdown list having two possible values - "work in progress" or "complete", or a couple of radio buttons.
2. Create a Completion Status column in the SharePoint list. It could be a Yes/No column, Choice, or Single line of text.
3. When the user submits/saves the form, an item is created in the SharePoint list, with the value in the Completion Status column corresponding to the completion status field on your form.
4. If the user wants to edit the form again, they can click on the Edit link for the item in the SharePoint list to make further changes.
5. When the user has finished adding information to the form, they change the status to "Complete".

Following these steps will give you a way to distinguish between forms that are work-in-progress and forms that are complete. What happens next (initiate a workflow, do some calculations, etc.) depends on how you intend to process the submitted forms. However, the basic principle is that instead of initiating processing when the form is submitted you initiate it when the value of the Completion Status field changes to "Complete".

Answer (score 0):

You can save it  as "draft" by creating a status field but this is still using the SUBMIT rule. User can edit it to continue and will think that it is still in "draft" since in Status field, it shows "draft"

Then you can add rules like some fields/sections are hidden unless certain fields are completed to avoid a very long InfoPath form. OR you can separate each sections in views. This will prevent overwhelming the users with a very long form and a lot of fields to fill out.